# Windows 8 lost after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on secondary drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I had two hard drives with windows 8 on one and data on the other.

I built the PC and installed windows 8 on it two years ago.  I had intended to set it up as dual boot but got put off by the UEFI issues.  However, having done it successfully in work on a single drive, I thought I'd give it a shot again, (stupidly late at night).

I shrunk the second drive to free space, disabled secure boot and booted into Ubuntu live.  I installed Ubuntu and downloaded boot repair as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

I omitted:

```
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
```

as it had caused the boot-repair install to fail on the work PC.

The boot repair app highlighted issues with gparted but I decided to reboot, expecting to boot into windows.
Instead, the grub menu appears with no windows manager option.
I can't get into windows 8.  I had forgotten to create the recovery disk and I'm wondering what should I do.  It's pretty bad as all my stuff/programs is in the windows 8 partitions.

Comment: Boot-Repair has been updated and have versions for all current versions of Ubuntu. If you now change to saucy it will not work. Post link to summary report above so then we can see all the details and what is where.

Comment: It doesn't give a link.  It says  GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.

Comment: That is saying you have a gpt partitioned drive and want to install grub to BIOS boot. It has to have a bios_grub partition for grub to correctly install to gpt drives. Windows only boots from gpt drives with UEFI. And best if both Windows are in same boot mode or both UEFI or both BIOS. Need Boot-Repairs summary report to really know.

Comment: Thanks oldfred. I'm afraid I just abandoned ubuntu and used the windows 8 installation CD as per http://heatware.net/windows-8/error-unknown-file-system-grub-rescue-starting-boot-windows-8-linux/  Maybe it is best to install ubuntu and windows on the same primary drive?

Comment: If you have two drives, always better to have Windows on one drive and Ubuntu on the other drive. But with new UEFI/BIOS systems, you must be sure to install both systems in the same boot mode, either both UEFI or both BIOS. With Ubuntu on separate drive then better to use gpt as Ubuntu can boot BIOS or UEFI from gpt where Windows only boots BIOS from MBR and only UEFI from gpt.

Comment: Oh, I thought there was an issue with primary/ secondary drives.  Is there a simple way to recover Ubuntu on the second drive from windows?

Comment: Windows does not work with Ubuntu, it does not see it and often creates issues as it "forgets" to include any Linux partitions when it rewrites partition table. Use Windows tools for Windows and Linux tools for Linux. When I said two drives that is the Linux definition or two physical drives not the undefined Windows drive which may be a partition or a physical drive.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of people successfully dual booting win 8.  Surely the grub can be modified in Ubuntu/ Win 8 so that a dual boot is possible?  Currently Win 8 -> SSD Ubuntu -> HDD but Ubuntu not visible.

Comment: You really need to run Boot-Repair and post link to summary report, or else we just talk past each other as to what issues may be.

Comment: Got it.  Unfortunately linux is in the phantom partition that I no longer have access to.  I'll look into but it may be a while before I have any feedback, thanks for your help, Sean.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal but may help someone not overly familiar with Ubuntu such as myself.

I disconnected the secondary drive and booted up as normal

This gave me a prompt

`grub rescue>`

I followed this [guide](http://heatware.net/windows-8/error-unknown-file-system-grub-rescue-starting-boot-windows-8-linux/)

1. Insert win 8 installation CD.
2. Boot from the CD
3. Select Repair PC
4. Automatic Repair, next I tried system restore, then command prompt

At the command prompt I entered the following:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Then exit, shutdown, remove the CD and it booted into windows for me.  I shutdown and reconnected the secondary drive.  I don't have Ubuntu but at least I have windows back where all my programs are.  Back to the drawing board with Ubuntu on two drives for me.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your Windows 8 partition is there and its EFI partition,if it is you can try installing http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ otherwise you need to rebuild MBR and possibly grub afterwards.

Comment: Thanks XperianX.  How do I check to see if the Windows 8 partition is there and it EFI partition?

Comment: It is first partition on disk few MB big http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition#Windows

Comment: I just remembered,check boot order in bios or just specify hard disk on which Windows is installed to boot first.

Comment: Thanks XperianX. It appears to be still present. `~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
└─sda2   8:2    0 118.9G  0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
├─sdb3   8:19   0 830.9G  0 part /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
├─sdb4   8:20   0  46.9G  0 part /
├─sdb5   8:21   0    82G  0 part /home
└─sdb6   8:22   0  16.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
`